# Excel VBA - best way to store and rewrite nested data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a vba tool that breaks out nested data from a particular cell and repeats the other fields in each row for each nest value.  For example, the following:

```
Bldg 3000 | Floor 2 | 201, 20, 203
Bldg 7010 | Floor 1 | 110, 151
```

Should become:

```
Bldg 3000 | Floor 2 | 201
Bldg 3000 | Floor 2 | 202
Bldg 3000 | Floor 2 | 203
Bldg 7010 | Floor 1 | 110
Bldg 7010 | Floor 1 | 151
```

I started making the below program to import all the spreadsheet data into an array; however, I wasn't sure how to handle the nested values so this is just copying the spreadsheet as is so far:

```
Sub import()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim listing() As Variant
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export Worksheet")
Set rng = ws.Cells.CurrentRegion
spreadsheet = rng
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
ws2.Name = "test"
For i = 1 To UBound(spreadsheet, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(spreadsheet, 2)
        Debug.Print spreadsheet(i, j)
        ws2.Cells(i, j) = spreadsheet(i, j)
        'Need to somehow get nested data in the appropriate cells and count/store the 
        'unique words so that when I write to sheet, I can have another nested loop that repeats
        'all row data except the target column which loops through unique words and breaks them 'out 1 x 1
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

So I tried to incorprate a function that get the unique words.  It worked before I made the array that stores the unique words as two dimensional, so that I can store the row number as well as each uniqe word (in our example above, I'd have 3 entries with a row number of 1, and their corresponding values would be 201, 202, and 203.  Then I'd have 2 entries with a row number of 2, with the unique values being 110 and 151).

My attempt is below and I receive an error when I try to redim preserve the multidimensional array.  I'm sure this isn't the best approach and any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Dim words() As Variant
Dim strng As String
Dim myRng As Range, r As Range
ReDim words(0, 2)

Function getWords_new(st As String, address As String, row As Long)
'Dim words() As Variant
'ReDim words(0, 2)
'ReDim words(0)
word_length = Len(st)
Start = 1
If word_length = 0 Then
    words(UBound(words, 1), 1) = row
    words(UBound(words, 1), 2) = "NULL"
Else:
    For i = 1 To word_length
        If Mid(st, i, 1) = "," Then
            finish = i
            Gap = finish - Start
            If Gap > 0 Then
                word = Mid(st, Start, Gap)
                lim = UBound(words, 1)
                If lim > 0 Then
                    'ReDim Preserve words(1 To lim + 1, 1 To UBound(words, 2))
                    'from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095182/redim-preserve-with-multidimensional-array-in-excel-vba
                    y = UBound(words, 2)
                    ReDim Preserve words(lim + 1, y)
                    words(lim, 2) = word
                Else:
                    ReDim Preserve words(lim + 1, UBound(words, 2))
                    words(0, 2) = word
                End If
                Start = finish + 1
            End If
            ElseIf i = word_length Then
            word = Mid(st, Start, word_length)
            lim = UBound(words, 1)
            If lim > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve words(lim + 1, UBound(words, 2))
                words(lim, 2) = word
            Else: words(0, 2) = word
            End If
            Start = finish + 1
        End If
    Next i
End If
word_count = UBound(words, 1)

'If word_count > 0 Then
'    'Debug.Print address & " - Word count is: " & word_count
Debug.Print "Words are: "
    For i = 0 To UBound(words, 1)
        For j = 0 To UBound(words, 2)
'        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats")
'        lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'        ws.Cells(lr + 1, 1) = address
'        ws.Cells(lr + 1, 2) = words(i)
'        ws.Cells(lr + 1, 3) = word_count
            Debug.Print words(i, j)
        Next j
'   Next i
'End If
End Function
```

Comment: You can only `ReDim` the last dimension of an array so if you really need to do it for both dimensions, you should use 2 seperated arrays.

Comment: Have a Split() function. It can convert a comma seperated string, into an array. Combine that with some logic, and you should be able to achieve your goal...

Comment: @UGP, thanks for the advice.  Sorry, but I don't fully understand.  Since I need to associate the orginal row ID with the words being stored, how would I associate the two separate arrays?

Comment: @Noceo, Thank you.  I should be able to use split to get the words much more efficiently.  I still have to figure out how to handle the storing of nested data

Comment: Use an array for each dimension.

Comment: Also if you want the row id, why not use the index of the array as that?

Comment: @UGP, since (in the example, row 1 would have 3 separate values (201,20,203), using the index wouldn't be possible (it would turn into Index 1, index 2, index 3 and then the values wouldn't be associated to row 1 repeated data anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you start with this in `Sheet1`:

[image]

and run this short macro:

```
Sub reprg()
    Dim N As Long, K As Long, s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    K = 1
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        v1 = s1.Cells(i, 1)
        v2 = s1.Cells(i, 2)
        ary = Split(s1.Cells(i, 3), ", ")
        For Each a In ary
            s2.Cells(K, 1) = v1
            s2.Cells(K, 2) = v2
            s2.Cells(K, 3) = a
            K = K + 1
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

you will get this in `Sheet2`:

[image]

Just make the necessary changes required to use your sheet names and column assignments.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best method of doing it but this is what I'd do

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlOutput As Range
Dim S1 As String


Sub SplitData()
    Set xlOutput = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5)
    For Each xlCell In Selection
        S1 = xlCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        Do Until InStr(1, S1, ",", vbTextCompare) < 1
            With xlOutput
                .Value = xlCell.Value
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = Mid(S1, 1, InStr(1, S1, ",", vbTextCompare) - 1)
            End With
            S1 = Trim(Mid(S1, InStr(1, S1, ",", vbTextCompare) + 1, Len(S1)))
            Set xlOutput = xlOutput.Offset(1, 0)
        Loop
        With xlOutput
            .Value = xlCell.Value
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = S1
        End With
        Set xlOutput = xlOutput.Offset(1, 0)
    Next xlCell
End Sub
```

Then just select the cells in the first column of data and run the code.  If you wanted to automatically select them, that can be done as well with just a small tweak to the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this (slightly oversimplified) code:

```
Sub SplitToSeperateRows()
    r = 1
    For i = 1 To 2
        stringToSplit = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "C")
        stringAsArray = Split(stringToSplit, ",")

        For j = 0 To UBound(stringAsArray)
            With Sheets("Sheet2")
                .Cells(r, "A") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A")
                .Cells(r, "B") = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "B")
                .Cells(r, "C") = stringAsArray(j)
                r = r + 1
            End With
        Next j

    Next i
End Sub
```