# Keep adding sheet data to a redim preserved array?

Tags: vba

I am trying to gather data from dozens of worksheets in a workbook and compile them all to be appended to a new `master` workbook.

This line: `ReDim varArray2 (1 To UBound(varArray, 2), 1 To UBound(varArray, 1))` keeps clearing out my preserved data from all worksheets when I try to make an overarching varArray2 to print all arrays at once to the new master worksheet.

What is causing the array to clear out and how can I fix it?

```
Option Explicit
Sub ws_Merge()


Dim k As Long, x As Long, j As Long
Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim varArray2() As Variant
ReDim varArray(1 To 11, 1 To 1)
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook


For Each ws In Worksheets

With wb.ActiveSheet

        For j = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            If .Cells(j, 1) <> "" Then
                x = x + 1
                ReDim Preserve varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To x)
                    For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                        varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
                    Next
            End If
        Next

    End With

    Next ws

ReDim varArray2(1 To UBound(varArray, 2), 1 To UBound(varArray, 1))

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    For j = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
            varArray2(j, k) = varArray(k, j)
        Next
    Next

    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How does `varArray2` look in the debugger's Watch window?  Is it really the array, or is the problem in the `.Range` assignment?  If you're starting with `2`, shouldn't the ending cell be `UBound(varArray,2) + 1`?

Comment: You can't. See [ReDim Preserve with multidimensional array in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25095182/4088852).